# Laravel - Access The Authenticated User In A Model Observer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I followed the documentation for creating a model observer here `https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers`.

But when I try and access the authenticated user I get `null`.

How can I access the authenticated user in the model observer?

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Customer;

class CustomerObserver
{
    public function created(Customer $customer)
    {
        dd(auth()->user());
    }

    public function updated(Customer $customer)
    {
        dd(auth()->user());
    }
}
```

I've also tried this inside the `Customer` model and it returns null as well.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::updated(function ($model) {
        dd(auth()->user());
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the observer need registering? How does it "know" which model to observe?

Comment: I have registered it in `config/app.php >         App\Providers\ObserverServiceProvider::class, > Customer::observe(CustomerObserver::class);` so it works.

Comment: Are you actually logged in (just checking ;))? If you `dd(auth()->user())` in your controller, do you get a logged in user? Are you using the default auth provider, or a custom provider? I.e, do you need to pass the provider name?

Comment: @fubar yes I am logged in. I am using a customer auth provider with the same details as the user provider just a different model and table. But it is all setup and working correctly.

Comment: What I am thinking is that the authentication comes after the model observer therefore it isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so stupid mistake on my end.

Thanks `@fubar` for the tip.

I was using a custom authentication provider so I needed to do this:

```
dd(auth()->guard('admin')->user());
```